# Error "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered"

Tags: ms-access, oledb, oledbconnection

The error occurs since i installed my vb.net application on a newer pc.
Microsoft O365 64bit is installed on that pc.

The connection string i use to connect my Microsoft Access Database is:
`GetSQLConnectie = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=empty;Data Source=C:\test\accdb"`

I changed the target platform to x64 for my setup deployment.
In ODBC data source management (64bit) there is an ACEODBC.DLL v16 installed. I changed the code but got the same issue.

`GetSQLConnectie = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=empty;Data Source=C:\test\accdb"`

On previous systems i fixed the problem to install office 32-bit versions or the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.

Now i found information that you no longer need to install the ACE Redistributable to use the ACE OLEDB provider (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0, or Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) if you have O365.

Is there a way to stay on O365 64-bit and resolve the issue?

Thanks.